# Deleting page tabs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-php-sdk, http-delete

When I try delete a page tab, facebook throws me an error.

```
$facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID', 'post', array(
    'method' => 'delete',
    'access_token' => PAGE_TOKEN
));
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request.**

---

```
$facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID', 'get', array(
    'method' => 'delete',
    'access_token' => PAGE_TOKEN
));
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.**

---

```
$facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID', 'delete', array(
    'access_token' => PAGE_TOKEN
));
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.**

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a HTTP DELETE request.

Either change 'post' to 'delete' and remove the unnecessary 'method => delete' or change 'post' to 'get'  and leave the 'method => delete' in place

Comment: With delete instead post, and without method: **Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.**, Otherwise: **Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request** :(

Comment: Are you sure you have the page ID and tab ID correct then? that error means 'you're trying to do something to an object that isn't supported' - it usually means using a GET when it should be a POST or vice-versa, but it could just be that your request is wrong

Comment: You're right. Sorry and THANKS! Final code: **$facebook->api('/PAGEID/tabs/app_TABID), 'delete', array('access_token' => PAGE_TOKEN));**